# Cross Reference SQL Data

Tags: sql, cross-reference

I have two tables like this:

```
Table 1
id    code     classID
43    EDGE-10  13

Table 2
classID   class
13        T-Shirts
```

how can I cross reference the classID in the first table to join the class to table 1 in a view?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
        Table2 t2   ON  t1.classID = t2.classID
```

Maybe also have a read here

[Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)